# Bootstrap menu always collapsed issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am facing an issue in making my bootstrap menu collpased by default but everything is working fine till 991px i need that thing to be done till max-width of 1400px. Any help appreciated.

http://www.theo2.co.in/fashionongo/

Comment: So you want it to be closed at all times?

Comment: ya as when its like 991px.

Comment: You have to create your own css media query

Comment: I am using a theme dont know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure how your theme was built but try this: In your custom CSS file add a media query like:

```
@media (max-width: 2000px) {
.navbar-header {
    float: none;
}
.navbar-left,.navbar-right {
    float: none !important;
}
.navbar-toggle {
    display: block;
}
.navbar-collapse {
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}
.navbar-fixed-top {
    top: 0;
    border-width: 0 0 1px;
}
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none!important;
}
.navbar-nav {
    float: none!important;
    margin-top: 7.5px;
}
.navbar-nav>li {
    float: none;
}
.navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.collapse.in{
    display:block !important;
}
}
```

They key to the code is the **2000px** part. If screen size gets over 2000px the menu will open. Try it and see if it work on your site